# Railscast 274: self[column]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In railscast #274 Ryan has the following code in the User model:

```
def generate_token(column)
  begin
    self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
end
```

What does self[column] refer to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It refers to the method [[]=](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) at `ActiveRecord` objects. An alias to calling:

```
  write_attribute(column, SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64)
```

At your example.

It's almost the same as doing `self.attribute_name = "some-value"`. The difference is that if you do something like:

```
user["unknown_attribute"] = "some value"
```

You'll get a `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute unknown_attribute` while  this:

```
user.unknown_attribute = "some value"
```

Will cause a `NoMethodError: undefined method unknown_attribute= for #<User:0x7185e611>`

Comment: So is it the same thing or ALMOST the same thing? If so, what's the difference?

Comment: Example with the difference included in the answer.

Comment: @MichaelGlaz [This is the source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/28c1a81f9a06c8bc268881771ffc1b678cf944a4/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb#L380) if you're curious to see more.